# Can I use these components in my project or are their licenses incompatible?

Tags: software, licensing, foss

I have currently two software licensing projects at hand: one is based on the eclipse (v2) framework and the in the other the codebase is proprietary.

In the Eclipse project, we created and linked a module to the Eclipse codebase and also link an Apache library (dll) to it.

In the project using the proprietary codebase we link our own code to an LGPL 2.1 library and to an Apache2 library (both dll)

Can i use these components in the described way? Can i use a proprietary outbound license for both projects?